# Permission denied (publickey) - Troubleshooting sshd pulling public keys from LDAP Server

Tags: ssh, debian, ldap, openldap, public-key

1.
Problem Summary:

Hi, recently, in our infrastructure production environment, new users are unable to ssh into a debian jump server. 
The jumpserver' SSH daemon retrieves the SSH public keys from the LDAP Server. 
We verified sshd local configuration, sshd logs, LDAP public keys presence and we are unable to fully understand what is preventing the users to effectively login.

2.
Details (Configuration Files):

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for

Port 22

# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes


# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding no
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
UseDNS no


Match Address 172.20.1.*,10.*
    PasswordAuthentication yes


Match Group ldap-user
    AuthorizedKeysFile /dev/null
    AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/ourcompanyname/scripts/ldap_keys.sh
    AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

Script which queries the LDAP:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(whoami) = nobody ]; then
  /usr/local/bin/ldap_ssh_keys -f /tmp/ssh_keys.log -b dc=prod,dc=ourcompany -u ldaps://ldap.prod.ourcompanydomain -l DEBUG $1
else
  echo "should be run as user nobody"
fi
```

3.
What we tried (logs):

User tries to connect to the server (client side)

```
 myusername@laptophostname currentfoldr % ssh -vvv myusername@jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain
    OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myusername/.ssh/config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
    debug2: resolving "jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain" port 22
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct
    debug1: Connecting to jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain [172.20.1.66] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
    debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain:22 as 'myusername'
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain
    debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    debug3: send packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug3: receive packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
    debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
    debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug3: send packet: type 30
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug3: receive packet: type 31
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VKd849z2c6XlUO3p7GnZpwVIwtdhI6Gl+6EsTImYwLI
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.20.1.66
    debug1: Host 'jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: send packet: type 21
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: receive packet: type 21
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6pLYo9k0m0LK2E4Og69uAmu24SyTOX8FUX91/HDx1gk
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
    debug3: send packet: type 5
    debug3: receive packet: type 7
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug3: receive packet: type 6
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
    debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6pLYo9k0m0LK2E4Og69uAmu24SyTOX8FUX91/HDx1gk
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    myusername@jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain: Permission denied (publickey).
    myusername@mylaptopname:currentfoldername % ssh -vv myusername@jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain 
    OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myusername/.ssh/config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
    debug2: resolving "jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain" port 22
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct
    debug1: Connecting to jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain [172.20.1.66] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
    debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain:22 as 'myusername'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
    debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
    debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VKd849z2c6XlUO3p7GnZpwVIwtdhI6Gl+6EsTImYwLI
    debug1: Host 'jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6pLYo9k0m0LK2E4Og69uAmu24SyTOX8FUX91/HDx1gk
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    **debug1: Offering public key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:6pLYo9k0m0LK2E4Og69uAmu24SyTOX8FUX91/HDx1gk
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply**
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss
    **debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    myusername@jbox01.prod.ourcompanydomain: Permission denied (publickey).**
```

User tries to connect to the server (server side):

```
Mar 16 12:49:55 jbox01 sshd[26063]: Connection from 172.20.101.6 port 63442 on 172.20.1.66 port 22
Mar 16 12:49:56 jbox01 sshd[26063]: Failed publickey for myusername from 172.20.101.6 port 63442 ssh2: RSA SHA256:6pLYo9k0m0LK2E4Og69uAmu24SyTOX8FUX91/HDx1gk
```

We have also compared the SHA256 of the key contained in LDAP with the key the user is providing to the server and they match.
Any suggestion on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with testing whether the custom script returns the expected SSH key.

Try something like this:

```
runuser -u nobody /opt/ourcompanyname/scripts/ldap_keys.sh myusername
```

Also check whether *myusername* is member of group *ldap-user*:

```
id myusername
```

If the user is not member of group *ldap-user* the sshd_config directives inside directive `Match Group ldap-user` do not apply. Rather the global settings or defaults are used.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for supporting. 
The script seems running correctly: 

runuser -u nobody /opt/ourcompanyname/scripts/ldap_keys.sh myusername prints out


ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2qER1d2/FGfnJ/E6I8Rx+e9z8mw278XQwSa8fP/vDRD2cfv4Ncu94YQh6P4b7vGkwCJ/WnTKlkFpyNzle7Qd+KzAnp4NothercharactersofmykeyOCSA1DAohlMf6a+x1HpBF5 myemail@myemail.ourdomain

and this seems the same of /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: Incresing the logging level to DEBUG3 I now see:

Mar 20 09:29:54 jbox01 sshd[6421]: debug3: checking match for 'Group ldap-user' user lsambolino host 172.20.101.18 addr 172.20.101.18 laddr 172.20.1.66 lport 22
Mar 20 09:29:54 jbox01 sshd[6421]: debug1: user lsambolino does not match group list ldap-user at line 92

So it appears to me the sshd isn't finding any rule and then it searches for a local .ssh key (and there is not). I now believe something is wrong in importing the correct users and groups from LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually solved it by:

1. Adding the missing *ldap-user* group membership in the LDAP portal for some of the users
2. **Restarting** the jbox node to let the PAM system refresh its cache. **By getent groups** it is now possible to see the new users inside the *ldap-user* group

Thanks Michael for support